# How to add a link and downloadable file to this code?

Tags: html, css

Hey all I am hoping you guys can help me? I am trying to edit this and need to be able to add a url when someone clicks the button. Also the ability to download a file. What would I add for this?

```
                <div class="optin" data-lb="editable-optional">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <img src="img/books-small.png" class="minor-image" />
                <p>Enter your email to download the guide</p>
                <div>
                    <input id="header-button" type="submit" value="Free Instant Access »" onclick="javascript:return false"/>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the [<a> tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)? That is the general go-to for basic link related stuff.

Comment: How would I add the link to the button?

Comment: Right now when I click on it the link doesn't take me anywhere even with the a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the download tag. You can add the image inside the a tag.

```html
<div class="optin" data-lb="editable-optional">
 <div class="shadow"></div>
  <a href="img/books-small.png" download><img class="minor- 
  image"/></a>
  <p>Enter your email to download the guide</p>
<div>
<input id="header-button" type="submit" value="Free Instant Access »" onclick="javascript:return false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using <div> s is not recommended by W3C standards.
Why don’ t you just use the hyperlink <a> tag:

```
<a href=" https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">Free Instant Access »</a>
```

You can use CSS styles to make the hyperlink <a> look like a buttom 
(taken from W3Schools):

```
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```